# AJAX call returning previous version of script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call which is fired onclick - it all works fine and gives the desired result, apart from the fact that it's still outputting an old version of the details.php page.

HTML:

```
 <div id="productList">
  <h3>Product List</h3><hr />
    <table width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            $q1 = "select * from products";
            $r1 = mysqli_query($cxn,$q1) or die ('Error Q1');

            while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)) {
                echo "<tr id='$row1[pCode]' onclick=\"getDetails($row1[pCode]);\" >
                <td>$row1[Description]</td>
                <td>$row1[SalePrice]</td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>

    </table>
</div>

<div id="productDetails">
    <h3>Product Details</h3><hr />
    <div id="specifics"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDetails(pCode){

        var page = "includes/details.php?pCode=" + pCode +"&success=yes";
        var xReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xReq.open("GET",page,false);
        xReq.send(null);
        var serverResponse = xReq.responseText;
        document.getElementById("specifics").innerHTML=serverResponse;
    }

</script>
```

The php simply queries the database based on the pCode value passed to the url and retrieves the information and outputs, but it's reverting to the old version of the file which doesn't even exist!!

Comment: It sounds like the results of the call are cached somewhere. Maybe in the browser cache, maybe on an intermediate server (Apache?)

Comment: I'm developing on Apache but even when uploaded the same thing happens - frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the result is cached. Since you may not have control about other users' browser cache, a solution is to query the page using a random number. Something like this:

```
var page = "includes/details.php?pCode=" + pCode +"&success=yes&random=" + Math.random();
```

Thus the result will not be cached and you will always get the latest version.

Comment: That seems to have done the job, thank you very much

Comment: I'll fix it by adding over here. :)